# "Parse error: unexpected '['"

Tags: 8

I have this error when I connect to my site from the Internet. (I don't have it if connected locally via 192.168.0.xx/drupal8.)

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /volume1/web/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Security/RequestSanitizer.php on line 156

The line causing the error is the following one.

```
    if ($key !== '' && ((string) $key)[0] === '#' && !in_array($key, $whitelist, TRUE)) {
```

I have PHP 5.6 and Drupal 8 installed on a Synology server.

What should I do?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That is an error that happens on PHP 5.6 and earlier versions](https://3v4l.org/pTpqv). Since [Drupal 8.7.x requires PHP 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2938726), you need to change the PHP version the server is using.

You could not see the error locally either because the PHP version is different or because locally you are using a different Drupal 8.x version (for example, Drupal 8.6.0).

Comment: Thank's . That whas the solution